# Why is CVaR positively homogeneous?

Tags: convex-optimization

I am reading the article "Some remarks on the Value at Risk and the Conditional Value at Risk" by G. Pflug. The author claims that CVaR is positively homogeneous. That is,
Given a loss function $X(x,\omega)$ of the decision variables $x$ and the uncertainty $\omega$, we have that
$$CVaR_\alpha(kX)=kCVaR_\alpha(x)$$
I am starting from the definition of CVaR but I do not seem to be heading anywhere.
$$
CVaR_\alpha(kX)=\min_{\beta\in\mathbb{R}}(\beta+\frac{1}{1-\alpha}\int_{\omega\in\mathbb{R}}\max(0,kX(x,\omega)-\beta)p(\omega)d\omega)
$$
This is equal to
$$
CVaR_\alpha(kX)=\min_{\beta\in\mathbb{R}}(\beta+\frac{1}{1-\alpha}\int_{\omega:kX(x,\omega)\geq \beta}(kX(x,\omega)-\beta)p(\omega)d\omega)
$$
$$
CVaR_\alpha(kX)=\min_{\beta\in\mathbb{R}}(\beta+\frac{1}{1-\alpha}\int_{\omega:kX(x,\omega)\geq \beta}kX(x,\omega)p(\omega)d\omega-\frac{\beta}{1-\alpha}\int_{\omega:kX(x,\omega)\geq \beta}p(\omega)d\omega)
$$
$$
CVaR_\alpha(kX)=\min_{\beta\in\mathbb{R}}(\beta+\frac{1}{1-\alpha}\int_{\omega:kX(x,\omega)\geq \beta}kX(x,\omega)p(\omega)d\omega-\frac{\beta}{1-\alpha}(1-\alpha))
$$

$$
CVaR_\alpha(kX)=\min_{\beta\in\mathbb{R}}(\frac{1}{1-\alpha}\int_{\omega:kX(x,\omega)\geq \beta}kX(x,\omega)p(\omega)d\omega)
$$

Any advise on how to continue?